# Programa crashea al usar eof()

Tags: c++

haciendo un programa de inventario de una librería, me he encontrado con que al usar archivo.eof() en cierta parte del programa, resulta en el crasheo inmediato de este. Es extraño, ya que llevaba probando este programa, con esta función hace rato; sin embargo de la nada empezó a crashear por esto.
Descubrí que este es el problema, ya que al eliminar esta simple parte, el programa funciona correctamente; sin embargo, esta es necesaria para su funcionalidad.
Adjunto mi código y acepto cualquier sugerencia. Nótese que el problema se encuentra en la función "leer".

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Libro{
    char titulo[50];
    char apellido[30];
    char nombre[20];
    char precio[9];
    char editorial[30];
    char isbn[20];
    char copyright[15];
    char ejemplares[4];
    char estado[2];
};

int intro();
int leer(Libro inventario[]);
void listar(Libro inventario[], int lineas);
void recibirEnvio(Libro inventario[], int lineas);
void vender();
void informacionLibro();


int main(){
    int opcion=0, lineas;
    Libro inventario[100];
    cout<<"Buenos dias, bienvenido a Libro y algo mas\n";
    lineas = leer(inventario);
    while(opcion>=0){
        opcion = intro();
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                listar(inventario,lineas);
                break;
            case 2:
                recibirEnvio(inventario, lineas);
                lineas = leer(inventario);
                break;
            case 3:
                vender();
                break;
            case 4:
                informacionLibro();
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"La opcion no existe, intente de nuevo";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int intro(){
    int opc;
    cout<<"\tMenu\n";
    cout<<"1.Listar inventario\n2.Recibir envio\n3.Vender Libro\n4.Ver informacion de un titulo\n\tSeleccion: ";
    cin>>opc;
    return opc;
}
int leer(Libro inventario[]){
    ifstream entrada("..\\inBooks.txt");
    int lineas=0;
    if(!entrada){
        cout<<"El archivo de inventario no se ha podido leer";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; !entrada.eof(); i++){
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].titulo,50,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].apellido,50,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].nombre,20,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].precio,9,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].editorial,30,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].isbn,20,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].copyright,15,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].ejemplares,4,',');
        entrada.getline(inventario[i].estado,2,'\n');
        lineas++;
    }
    return lineas;
}
void listar(Libro inventario[], int lineas){
    for(int i = 0; i<lineas; i++){
        cout<<"Titulo: "<<inventario[i].titulo<<". Apellido: "<<inventario[i].apellido<<". Nombre: "<<inventario[i].nombre<<". Precio: "<<inventario[i].precio<<". Editorial: "<<inventario[i].editorial<<". ISBN: "<<inventario[i].isbn<<". Fecha de copyright: "<<inventario[i].copyright<<". Numero de ejemplares: "<<inventario[i].ejemplares<<". Estado de disponibilidad: "<<inventario[i].estado<<"."<<endl;
    }
}
void recibirEnvio(Libro inventario[], int lineas){
    fstream entsal("..\\inBooks.txt", ios::app);
    string isbnNuevo;
    bool final = true;
    int cantidad, temp, conta=0;
    cout<<"Ingrese isbn del titulo recibido: ";
    cin>>isbnNuevo;
    for(int i = 0; i<lineas; i++){
        cantidad =0;
        if(inventario[i].isbn == isbnNuevo){
            cout<<"Ingrese cantidad recibida: ";
            cin>>cantidad;
            temp = atoi(inventario[i].ejemplares)+cantidad;
            itoa(temp,inventario[i].ejemplares,10);
            ofstream salida("..\\inBooks.txt");
            for(int j = 0; j<lineas; j++){
                salida<<inventario[j].titulo<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].apellido<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].nombre<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].precio<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].editorial<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].isbn<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].ejemplares<<",";
                salida<<inventario[j].estado;
                if(j==lineas-1){
                    final = false;
                }
                if(final){
                salida<<endl;
                }
            }
            salida.close();
            break;
        }
        conta++;
        if(conta>=lineas){
            string temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese titulo nuevo: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<endl<<temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese apellido autor: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese nombre del autor: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese precio: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese editorial: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal<<","<<isbnNuevo;
            cout<<"Ingrese fecha de copyright: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese el stock: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal;
            cout<<"Ingrese estado: ";
            cin>>temporal;
            entsal<<","<<temporal;
            break;
        }
    }
    entsal.close();
    cout<<"Titulo ingresado"<<endl;
}
void vender(){
    cout<<"vender";
}
void informacionLibro(){
    cout<<"informacion";
}
```

Comment: Probaste reemplazando `!entrada.eof()` por `entrada.good()`? Tal vez ocurra otro error que no estás detectando.

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de obtener los datos de un archivo txt es leer primero el archivo y después llamar al método `eof`, en tu caso lo estás haciendo al revés, muestro un ejemplo de como se lee un archivo:

```
void leerArchivo(){
    std::ifstream archivo("datos.txt");
    std::string linea;

    // primero leer archivo
    std::getline(archivo,linea,'.');

    // y después hacer un ciclo con método eof
    while(!archivo.eof()){
        std::cout<<linea; 
        std::getline(archivo,linea,'.');
    }

    archivo.close();
}
```

De esta manera se recorre por completo el archivo obteniendo línea por línea su contenido. Otro punto importante a tener en cuenta es que a partir de la segunda llamada a `getline` la función va a poner un salto de línea al comienzo del string línea representado por el carácter `\n`